# Combining image RGB channels

Tags: python, image, image-processing, numpy, computer-vision

I have some problems with combining image channels in one rgb image. I use skimage and numpy for solving my problems. On input we have photo like this http://rghost.ru/8gYDcq2T6. With `numpy.array` slicing, I slice image in 3 parts by its height, then I slice edges of image (5% of height and width). Now I am ready to calculate mean squared error for two parts (part1 and part2, then for part1 and part3) for best image combining. I shift one part relatively to another on 15 pixels (left, right, up, down) and take minimum of all shifts, then I knew two shifts (x,y coordinates) for part1 and part2 and part1 and part3, then I use`numpy.dstack` for combining channels, and it's all. But quality in end is not good, so what's my mistake? I think problems with combining images in end using dstack, but cant solve it, coz dont understand, how to do it. There is my code:

```
    from skimage import data, io
    from numpy import *

    def metrics(first, second, x, y):
    reshaped_second = roll(second, x,0)
    reshaped_second = roll(reshaped_second, y, 1)
    reshaped_first = first
    mse = (((reshaped_first - reshaped_second) ** 2).sum())/(reshaped_first.size)
    return (mse, ncc, x, y)

    def align(path):
        image = data.imread(path)
        size = image.shape
        part1 = image[0 : size[0]/3, : ]
        part2 = image[size[0]/3 : 2*size[0]/3 , :]
        part3 = image[2*size[0]/3 : size[0], :]
        new_size = [min(part1.shape[0], part2.shape[0], part3.shape[0]), min(part1.shape[1], part2.shape[1], part3.shape[1])]
        part1 = part1[new_size[0]/100*5 : new_size[0] - new_size[0]/100*5, new_size[1]/100*5 : new_size[1] - new_size[1]/100*5]
        part2 = part2[new_size[0]/100*5 : new_size[0] - new_size[0]/100*5, new_size[1]/100*5 : new_size[1] - new_size[1]/100*5]
        part3 = part3[new_size[0]/100*5 : new_size[0] - new_size[0]/100*5, new_size[1]/100*5 : new_size[1] - new_size[1]/100*5]
        min_mse = 1000000000
        xx_1 = None
        yy_1 = None
        for x in range(-15, 16):
            for y in range(-15, 16):
                mse = metrics(part1, part2,x,y)
                if mse[0] <= min_mse:
                    xx_1 = mse[2]
                    yy_1 = mse[3]
                    min_mse = mse[0]

        min_mse = 1000000000
        xx_2 = None
        yy_2 = None
        for x in range(-15, 16):
            for y in range(-15, 16):
                mse = metrics(part1, part3,x,y)
                if mse[0] <= min_mse:
                    xx_2 = mse[2]
                    yy_2 = mse[3]
                    min_mse = mse[0]
        part2 = roll(part2, xx_1, 0) # numpy.roll()
        part2 = roll(part2, yy_1, 1)
        part3 = roll(part3, xx_2, 0)
        part3 = roll(part3, yy_2, 1)
        photo = dstack((part3,part2,part1))
        io.imshow(photo)
        io.show(
```

After execution of program I get such photo: http://rghost.ru/6fqqmFCnM, its first test image, on others worse. But want like better quality

What can I do? Thank you for help.

**PROBLEM FOUND: problem was with type of reshaped_first and reshaped_second in metrics function, they were 'uint8', and when I calculated reshaped_first - reshaped_second it was undefined behavior and I get unrepresentative metric. So 5/6 test photos have good combining, but last its about 15-20 pixels error. So new question is about what metrics I should choose for this problem? I tried normalized cross-correlation, but it's worse than mean squared error, that I use now**

Comment: want like this http://rghost.ru/7vSHRb5zb

Comment: example of bad work: http://rghost.ru/85srVLqkW

Comment: This looks suspiciously like a homework question. Anyhow, you may wish to use a proper image alignment algorithm, such as the [ECC](http://www.learnopencv.com/image-alignment-ecc-in-opencv-c-python/)